# Static External IP addresses in Zone europe-west3 have entry point in California, US

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have several static IP Addresses in Google Cloud Platform in the zone europe-west3. However, I just noticed that they all are traced back to California, US, which totally defeats the purpose. They should resolve to Frankfurt!

It is not the same with south-eastasia static IP which correctly resolve in Singapore.

Why is it different with the europe ones?
I have privacy complaints for customers now.
Google support seems to be rather unavailable.

Comment: How do you KNOW they are traced back to california? Pos tthe stack trace

Comment: They are not in the US.

Comment: This IP for example is a static eruope-west3 zone IP which should be in Frankfurt.
35.198.121.133
However, from the comments and answer I guess its just a confusion, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

In general: an ip-address tells you nothing about the actual physical location of the system using that ip-address nor the jurisdiction the system falls under, because IP-addresses can by routed to every corner of the earth and beyond.

In absence of more reliable data points the geographical location *attributed* to an IP-address is usually taken from the contact information in the "ownership" records of the IP-address range. That will usually be the **street address of the head quarters** or the main network engineering department of an organisation, other IP-address ranges can be the property of local subsidiary companies with a **street addresses of a local branch office** and almost **never the address of the datacenter housing your server**.

Comment: Does it affect on the overall server response time/performance if the IP resolves as a US although it should  be German one when the request comes from Germany?